# Visual Studio Code, Tasks not asinging input variable, parsing a command

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to make a task build code for ESPRESSIF IDF natively in VSCode on Linux (Ubuntu 10) but I'm running into some issue with the following task:

```
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build Firmware",
            "group": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "idf.py",
            "args": ["build"],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            }    
        },

        {
            "label": "Flash Firmware",
            "group": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "idf.py",
            "args": ["-p","${input:setPort}","flash"],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": false
            }    
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
          "id": "setPort",
          "type" : "command",
          "command": "ls /dev/tty* | grep USB" }
        ]
}
```

But I getting the following error:

```
input variable 'variable' can only be of type 'prompt String', 'pickString', or 'command'.
```

The expected behavior was to assign the parsed output of `ls /dev/tty* | grep USB` like `/dev/ttyUSB0` to **setPort** and in term pass a command like **idf.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 flash** as part or the build process.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. (BTW, No, I don't what to use platfromIO :))

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if anyone had this problem? Should I open a feature or issue?

Comment: Hi, anyone know what's going on here?

I just tried:

```"inputs":  [{"id": "setPort","type" : "command","command": "/usr/bin/ls","args":["/dev/tty* | grep USB"],}]```

I also created a `getty.sh` scrip in the root of the project and replaced that with the command and still now way to get this running, it's now complaining that either the `ls` or the `gettty.sh` command is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference the fact that `${input:var}`only accepts the following:

Currently VS Code supports three types of input variables:

promptString: Shows an input box to get a string from the user.
pickString: Shows a Quick Pick dropdown to let the user select from several options.
command: Runs an arbitrary command.
Each type requires additional configuration attributes:

promptString:

description: Shown in the quick input provides context for the input.
default: Default value that will be used if the user doesn't enter something else.
pickString:

description: Shown in the quick pick provides context for the input.
options: An array of options for the user to pick from.
default: Default value that will be used if the user doesn't enter something else. It must be one of the option values.
command:

command: Command being run on variable interpolation.
args: Optional option bag passed to the command's implementation.

**Importan** for to understand (which lead to my error) is that `command` type only supports VScode commands. Which is why it never finds my **shell** commands.

> Shell
>
> Blockquote
>
> Blockquote

Comment: did you find a command to achieve what you wanted (i.e. running `ls`)?